# PHP: XMLWriter, elements like <br />

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

I've been using XMLWriter but I can't get it to print an element with a final slash instead of a closing tag.

```
$xml->startElement("wololo");
$xml->writeAttribute("ver", "1.0");
$xml->endElement();
```

That is outputing

```
<wololo ver="1.0"></wololo>
```

and I want it to output

```
<wololo ver="1.0" />
```

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/2asj3qhq)

Comment: It only does that when I use `fullEndElement()` here... What is your PHP & libxml version? (PHP 5.3.10 & libxml 2.7.8 here) If you are lower, can you upgrade? May be a fixed bug.

Comment: PHP 5.3.3 & libxml 2.7.7. Tried fullEndElement() but didn't work either. I will try to upgrade, however I would prefer not to, 'cause I don't think I would be able to upgrade the production server.